# Abstract machine for Java bytecode

Tags: jvm, bytecode, instrumentation, abstract-machine

I was wondering if anyone is familiar with an abstract machine that is capable of executing Java bytecode. Note I'm looking for something I can extend, and by abstract machine, I don't mean the JVM, as I need to specify the semantics.

Specifically, I am looking for a way to keep track of what is going to be on the stack at a given point of time, without actually having to simulate all the instructions by myself. Does anyone know of a good framework for this?

Answer (score 2):

Consider looking at the [MLJVM project](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/stg/research/projects/MLJVM/).  I've never really looked at the internals, but it appears to be a JVM implementation produced in such a way that one could potentially extend or experiment with the semantics.

It might be somewhat stale, and implements only a subset of the JVM, but I assume if you're really looking at experimenting with semantics you're unlikely to want the whole JVM.

Alternatively, the [Jikes Research Virtual Machine](http://jikesrvm.org/) is often a nice starting point.  The lines between "VM" and "Abstract Machine" start to blur at some point, and I suspect Jikes is close to that line, wherever it may be.